# script test if sccm is currently installing software

Tags: windows-installer, sccm

Have a script that reboots a large number of computers every 2 hours when no user is logged on. The script sleeps a random time up to 1 hour 59 minutes after being started before testing if a user is logged on and if no users reboots the computer.
We are deploying the script via an SCCM package with a repeat time of 2 hours and always rerun.

We don't want to interfere with SCCM installing software by rebooting mid SCCM install so it would be useful to know how to test if SCCM or any other service is currently installing software so that a reboot can be inhibited in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reboot script should stop the CcmExec service and wait for it to enter the stopped state.  It should only reboot once the service is stopped.  AFAICT when the service receives a stop signal it will safely complete all of its tasks including any ongoing installations.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read this through. If it works, that is an excellent solution Will test your solution out during a system reload Might take a few days to confirm and if it does I'll accept your answer

Comment: Meanwhile I am having trouble finding any documentation on the ccmexec service, ironically enough there is some documentation for unix and linux: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573937.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to document.  It's just a normal Windows service. This Powershell one-liner should work to stop it: Get-Service CcmExec | Stop-Service

Comment: Thanks I know how to start and stop the service. The issue is if it does as you say "safely complete all of its tasks including any ongoing installations" before stopping. That's the part I'd like to see documented and that is specific to ccmexec, not all windows services.  Since the systems I am working on do not have powershell enabled (not my decision) I am using VB script to do the stop via WMI calls. You have been very helpful and I appreciate that but I also need to consider what might happen when I deploy to several thousand computers without thorough investigation and testing. Cheers!

Comment: Some of the installs we deploy take hours to complete so I'm concerned that something might go wrong such as some timeout. For instance consider the issues raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178553/gracefully-handling-shutdown-of-a-windows-service  I'm not sating you are wrong, just that I need to be cautious. Thanks again

Comment: I understand your concerns.  FWIW I have found scarce little documentation by Microsoft that accurately describes the detailed behavior of SCCM.

Comment: To add to your consideration: [Here's some evidence of CcmExec self-inflicting harm related to rebooting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1569e1e2-91bc-435d-8998-beb817d5b453/waiting-for-user-logon?forum=configmanagergeneral).  That problem remains as of SCCM 2012 r2 sp1 cu2.  I just reproduced it this week.

Comment: Thanks for that link. The last few lines are re-assuring: "We have also added some logic into our automated reboots during setup, to stop the ccmexec service, wait for it to exit, wait another few seconds, then reboot. This does seem to have removed the issue, or at least significantly reduced the frequency."

Comment: @sdjuan I thought that was the most disconcerting line of all.  For when any other process or user causes a reboot, CcmExec isn't treated with those same kid gloves.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about user initiated reboots as they are few and far between in my environment and there should be a minimum, hopefully zero, of processes other than SCCM initiating reboot when SCCM is installing, so for me that is re-assuring. YMMV

Comment: You are a lucky admin. :)

Comment: Now that I have had a little time to try this out: ccmexec is a process not a service and sadly does not quit gracefully, at least not via vbscript/WMI which is what I am using. I tried closing and waiting for it to close and it killed an install of an chrome browser in a task sequence and the task sequence said the instal failed and when re-tried it failed again. win32_process has only terminate() to stop the process as far as I can tell. Doing more tests now.

Comment: Since it seems that ccmexec only runs when software is being installed, I'm thinking now to just test for ccmexec running and if so don't reboot in that case

Comment: nope, that won't work as ccmexec is running all the systems I checked even though not currently installing

Comment: `ccmexec` is *definitely* a service on all my clients.  It is named "SMS Agent Host" in the Services MMC console.  The Services console shows the WMI `DisplayName` _not_ the WMI `Name`.  The `CcmExec` service launches a process called `CcmExec.exe`.  You need to stop the service, not kill the process.

Comment: OOPS!, I see it in both the processes and services now. When I previously looked it was showing only in the processes. I'll test some more.

Comment: So a manual stop from the control panel services.msc of ccmexec aka 'sms agent host' during a task sequence installing 12 + MSIs followed by a restart did not stop the task sequence. It went right on through all the MSIs  and then restarted the computer BEFORE the stop did its things. I'm now treading in muddy water.

Comment: I have done testing now and accepted your answer. As mentioned I was unable to stop ccmexec when a task sequence was running which is OK as the script then does not try to reboot while that task sequence is running which is the desired outcome. I then tested stopping ccmexec when individually deploying a bunch of applications and programs and the service stopped gracefully and after reboot delay started as normal and continued with any remaining installs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for reporting your testing.  I learned a little in the process.

Comment: You could have SCCM cause your reboot script to be invoked using scheduled tasks.  CcmExec uses that same strategy to manage itself.

Comment: I relearned for the 1000th time to do a manual test before blaming the system. It was a script bug, a piece of code had disappeared from the script during a cleanup. Working again but I will still need weeks to completely confirm there are no issues. Here's the log output: starting script at 2/26/2016 8:47:42 AM
user is logged on 2/26/2016 8:48:43 AM
starting script at 2/26/2016 8:51:00 AM
stopping ccmexec
ccmexec is stopped
rebooting system at 2/26/2016 8:55:30 AM after a 4 minutes delay
starting script at 2/26/2016 8:59:23 AM